# How to computer two Euler Angles between two vectors

Tags: matrices, vectors, 3d, angle

*I have looked on here for an answer to my question however the answers I found were how to find the actual angle and not broken down into theida and phi so here is my question:*

If I have two vectors a and b how can I calculate the two Euler angles between them?

I do know the total angle is found by:

```
=arccos(Re(a⋅b)∥a∥∥b∥)
```

What I am looking for is this scenario:

[image]

where the red line is vector a and the purple line is vector b. The angle between them can be broke up onto the two planes. Those two angles are what I am trying to find.

Comment: These are not Euler angles. And your theida is probably our theta. This said, drop one of the component (to achieve a projection) and compute the scalar product in 2D.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I have posted an answer below. I think I follow the projection. Can you please let me know if you agree with what I posted please

Comment: I still disagree with your theida.

Comment: @YvesDaoust What do you see wrong with my theida? It should just be the i and k components only right? I thought that is what I did

Comment: I tried to tell you but you did not understand. http://www.thinkbabynames.com/meaning/0/Theida

Comment: @YvesDaoust ha so I guess that is not the popular angle name of choice for you then

Comment: What language is that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So given vector A = (2**i**,4**j**,5**k**) and vector B = (1**i**,3**j**,8**k**)

my theida (as shown in image above) would be:

```
cos(theida) = ((Ai,Ak) ⋅ (Bi,Bk)) / (||Ai,Ak|| * ||Bi,Bk||)
```

Therefore,

cos(theida) = (2*1) + (5*8) / (sqrt(2^2 + 5^2) * sqrt(1^2+8^2))

theida = acos(42/(sqrt(29)*sqrt(65)))

**theida = 14.68 deg**

and similarly:

```
cos(phi) = ((Ai,Aj) ⋅ (Bi,Bj)) / (||Ai,Aj|| * ||Bi,Bj||)
```

Therefore,

cos(phi) = (2*1) + (4*3) / (sqrt(2^2 + 4^2) * sqrt(1^2+3^2))

phi= acos(14/(sqrt(20)*sqrt(10)))

**phi= 8.13 deg**